# A minimal set of points in the plane, such that lines between them generate the whole plane

Tags: set-theory, euclidean-geometry

Under the axiom of choice, there exists a set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ which intersects every line in exactly two points (See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21470/subset-of-the-plane-that-intersects-every-line-exactly-twice)). As I understand, it is not clear whether the axiom of choice is necessary.

Let us consider the following weaker statement: There exists a set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ which satisfy both of the following conditions:

1. $A$ intersects every line in at most two points, and
2. For every $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ there are pair of points in $A$, such that $(x,y)$ sits on the line which connects them.

This surely holds under the axiom of choice. Is it known whether this weaker version holds witout choice?

Comment: Just to clarify the question: $(x,y)$  sits on the line between them means that $(x.y)$ is in the middle of points or just in the line?

Comment: Just in the line, not necessarily between the points. Thanks, i'll fix the question

Comment: Actually, this is what I meant. I can't belive that I missed this simple answer.  Thanks for the help! I think that the strenghthening you offered is not possible: 
Take three points in A which are not on the same line (and then the points themselves are counterexamples).

Comment: @user333618 Oh yes - or similarly any pair of pairs of points not determining a pair of parallel lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Originally from the comments:*

The answer is yes: consider any nontrivial circle in the plane. More generally, any smooth strictly convex closed curve does this.

It is not immediately clear how to strengthen the conditions to avoid this without getting an immediate negative answer.